Ubuntu 24.04 nautilus shortcut for "open terminal here"
In Ubuntu 24.04 I have "Open in Terminal" on the context menu when I select a folder, however how to add a keyboard shortcut so that Terminal opens in the current position? I had this feature with 18.04 but I don't see how to add it to 24.04

Just found this link: https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2023/05/open-terminal-other-emulator-ubuntu/
Not tried it so!
cheers
Thilo

While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - From Review
